# UseWebpackDevMiddleware replaced in dotnet core 6

Tags: webpack, .net-core

Dotnet core 6 is telling me:

```
'WebpackDevMiddleware.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder, WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions)' is obsolete: 'Use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions'
```

I have changed this `using` statement:

```
- using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
+ using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions;
```

And now VSCode shows these errors:

```
'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseWebpackDevMiddleware' and no accessible extension method 'UseWebpackDevMiddleware' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [API]csharp(CS1061)
'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseWebpackDevMiddleware' and no accessible extension method 'UseWebpackDevMidd(CS1061)
```

For the first line of this code:

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
{
  ProjectPath = Path.Join(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "../UI"),
  ConfigFile = "node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js",
  HotModuleReplacement = true
});
```

What change is required to make this compatible? (Better yet, where is the documentation for this breaking change?)

Comment: DId you ever figure out?  I have the same issue... thank you!

Comment: Yes; See my own answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the package references needed to be updated to include the specific `SpaServices` package, too:

```
- <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.1.17" />
+ <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="6.0.5" />
+ <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="3.1.25" />
```

Comment: What did you use to replace `UseWebpackDevMiddleware` since it's obsolete?  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't get round that warning, but the code now builds.

Comment: Oh ok, cool. So it still works?

Comment: Yes, my problem was that I needed to include the correct versions of the packages, hence the answer above. Not that I migrated away from the warned method. (Though, at some point, that will be necessary.)